# How to create user having a primary group with the same name using puppet script?

Tags: linux, puppet

I was reading [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-puppet-code-manifests-and-modules) and it suggests creating user by using this code:

```
user { 'myuser':
  ensure     => present,
  uid        => '1000',
  gid        => '1000',
  shell      => '/bin/bash',
  home       => '/home/myuser'
}
```

However, when I run it, throws following error:

> Error: Could not create user myuser: Execution of '/usr/sbin/useradd -g 1000 -G wheel -d /home/myuser -s /bin/bash -u 1000 -M myuser' returned 6: useradd: group '1000' does not exist

I made it to work with the following:

```
group {'myuser':
  ensure     => present
}

user { 'myuser':
  ensure     => present,
  uid        => '1000',
  gid        => 'myuser',
  shell      => '/bin/bash',
  home       => '/home/myuser'
}
```

But I am not sure whether is the right way. Is there a way to achieve what I want by just using the `user` puppet resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer depends on OS and/or provider you used to create an user. In your configuration it is `useradd`. According to [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd), when used with `-g` option:

> The group name must exist. A group number must refer to an already existing group.

Possible solution is to remove `gid`:

```
user { 'myuser':
    ensure     => present,
    uid        => '1020',
    shell      => '/bin/bash',
    home       => '/home/myuser',
    managehome => true,
}
```

Then puppet will automatically create poper group:

> root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/home# su myuser
>
> myuser@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/home$ id
>
> uid=1020(myuser) gid=1020(myuser) groups=1020(myuser)

Good idea is to add an option `managehome => true,`. It will:

> create the home directory when ensure => present, and delete the home directory when ensure => absent

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very straightforward, Puppet is trying to make the new user you are asking it to but is being told by the OS that it can't because a group with the GID you are specifying does not exist.

What you did to address this is correct but is arguably missing a couple things. First, you should specify more information about the group than just the name (as gathered form the resource title `'myuser'`). This is not a huge deal but in your first block both the user and the group will have a ID's of 1000. Whereas in your second block the GID will be generated however the OS determines to generate it. You can manage this more closely by specifying the Group's GID and then using that GID in your user declaration.

Secondly, since in Puppet order is not guaranteed you will want to account for the possibility that even with your group declared as you have it now, it may not always run first, say when the user resource comes before the group in the compiled catalog. In this case you will run into the same issue.

Here's one way you could address this:

```
group {'myuser':
  ensure     => present,
  gid        => 1000,
  before     = User['myuser']
}

user { 'myuser':
  ensure     => present,
  uid        => '1000',
  gid        => '1000',
  shell      => '/bin/bash',
  home       => '/home/myuser',
  requires   => Group['myuser']
}
```

Notice the `requires` and `before` parameters set in the user and group. Setting the `requires` parameter to `Group['myuser']` will ensure that the specified group is always applied before the user being declared. The same is true with `before` and either can be used to get the same outcome.

Another way to handle this is with the `notifies` and `subscribe`. Puppet has a great page regarding resource ordering: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html

Lastly, one of my favorites especially when used to order classes in a module's `init.pp` class is the resources chaining:

```
group {'myuser':
  ensure     => present,
  gid        => 1000
} ->
user { 'myuser':
  ensure     => present,
  uid        => '1000',
  gid        => '1000',
  shell      => '/bin/bash',
  home       => '/home/myuser'
}
```

This will also ensure the same configuration mentioned above and can really come in handy. Especially when ordering classes in a module's init as I said previously.

For example:

```
class sampleclass (
    $ensure,
)inherits sampleclass::params{
  class { 'sampleclass::accounts': } ->
  class { 'sampleclass::files': } ->
  class { 'sampleclass::repo': } ->
  class { 'sampleclass::links': } ->
  class { 'sampleclass::config': }
}
```

Hope this helps!